# MongoDB : Is there any specific Size allocated to a MongoDB Collection?

Tags: mongodb

We are Using Mongo DB for our Application .

I have a question with respect to Mongo Database Stores records in a collection .

Currently we have 7 collections present in our Mongo DB .

Please let me know , Is there any specific Size that is allocated to each collection ??  and is there any case that this Collection Size will be crossed if there are More records being instertd ??

Currently we are not using any  capped collections  .

Please let me know , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your limit is the disk space of your server (or shard)
There is no limit per database or collection size

Answer (score 1):

You have limitation on the size of the BSON document you are inserting. Currently it is 16 MB per document. Following link gives you some other limitation.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: Thanks ,the question is not related to the size of the Document , but the size of the collection , anyway thanks for responding .